# Loading an included php file every x'th second

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, include

I'm trying to load an included php file loading 4 random images from the database, every third second (while testing). This is my code, but it does not work.

```
function updateImage(){
    $('#ajax').load('includes/slideshow.php');
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval( 'updateImage()', 3000 );
});
```

Can anyone tell my how to fix this? (do i need to use Ajax? And how would that code look like?)

I should add that the div with the id 'ajax' is empty.

This is slideshow.php:

```
$select = new c_select();
$rows = $select -> select ("images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4");

foreach ($rows as $nogle => $row){
    echo "<a href='upload/".$row['img_name']."' data-lightbox='lightbox'><img src='upload/resize_".$row['img_name']."'></a>";
}
```

Okay, if i try to echo out php function time before the call, it shows up and refreshes = it works. But the sql call doesn't execute.

UPDATE: Seems like i should've used a simpler mysql call and a database connection in slideshow.php.

Comment: "but it does not work" what means???

Comment: I don't see anything syntactically wrong with your code.

Comment: @KevinB not wrong but not the best: `setInterval( 'updateImage()', 3000 );`

Comment: Yes, that's why i was very careful with how i worded that comment. :)

Comment: @A.Wolff `setInterval(updateImage, 3000)`

Comment: @AdamMerrifield absolutely

Comment: @A.Wolff its the load function that doesn't execute.

Comment: check your console for any error

Comment: I am a bit guessing. Probably you have a HTML page that contains a gallery with 4 images. Once per 3 seconds you want to update them to new random images. If so, your `setInterval` code is correct. Your function `updateImage` should update `src` attributes of these images. If your script knows all possible image URLs, you do not need AJAX. If it does not know image locations, then call AJAX to get 4 random URLs. And then set them to `src`-s of your images.

Comment: @Sanja The file slideshow.php contains a simple sql call: SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4

Comment: @Sultenhest, sorry, but I do not understand the purpose of your comment. You need to use your JavaScript to update HTML of page that contains the gallery and your script.

Comment: Can you show us includes/slideshow.php? Your ajax js works for me. So your problem is in php file.

Comment: you need to nest it my friend...

Comment: @jacouh includes/slideshow.php is just a file containing a simple mysql : SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than setting an arbitrary 3 seconds, because this is an ajax request, why don't you use the success callback of a previous response to trigger the next request?

You could do that like this:

```
function updateImage(){
  $('#ajax').load('includes/slideshow.php', function(){
    setTimeout(updateImage, 3000);
  });
};

updateImage();
```

Now we are waiting for a request to finish before we send off another one. This way, you can pace the requests to the server a little more evenly. And if the server ever begins to slow down, this will slow down accordingly too, rather than continuing to hammer the server with requests it can't handle.

Comment: I tested this, it's bad idea, as $.load() is asynchronous, the image loading will be accelerated according to time, as timers generated by setTimeout() are accumulated. Might use $.get() instead.

Comment: I'm not sure you're understanding how this works. The whole point of using the callback on `.load` is that it won't generate a new request until a previous request has finished. This will only refresh at a maximum rate of 1 req per second. There is no "accumulation" of timers, as you put it.

Comment: +1, You are right, I noticed now your usage of setTimeout() instead of setInterval(). Bravo!!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't return anything at all. I'm starting to wonder if i'm placing the code the wrong place. Right now its at the bottom of my index file right below a jquery and a jquery-min include. I'm trying to include slideshow.php in a file included on the index.

Comment: You don't need both a `jquery` and a `jquery-min`... In fact, it's likely you'll run into problems if you have more than one without taking special actions to prevent them from colliding w one another.

Comment: @maček Right now it works, with the timer, but it doesn't execute the mysql call.

Answer (score 0):

Well I have a feeling that maybe the browser caches the response of that URL and uses the cached version every time, so to make sure you get a fresh copy every time, add a parameter to the URL, try replacing your function with this

```
function updateImage(){
    $('#ajax').load('includes/slideshow.php?'+new Date().getTime());
}
```

Hope it works for you.